# PDFX Compliance error - OutputIntent profile not 'prtr'

Tags: pdf, itext, preflight

Using iTextSharp 5.5.0 we embed Watermark text to PDF documents that are compliant with PDF X4. The output PDF when analyzed with Adobe Acrobat Preflight fails for PDF X4 compliant with below error:

> OutputIntent profile not 'prtr'

Any suggestion for fixing this issue with iTextSharp will be helpful. Attached screenshot of Preflight output from Adobe Acrobat.

[image]

Comment: Some standards (such as PDF/A, PDF/X,...) require that you define an *output intent*. We have an example where we add an output intent using iText 7 in order to comply with the PDF/A-1B standard in [the iText 7 jump-start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-7-creating-pdfua-and-pdfa-documents). PDF/X isn't one of the priorities for iText, since we're not that active in the printing industry, but you can use the same functionality to add an output intent of type prtr.

Comment: If your original PDF was PDF/X compliant but the result is not, your code to *embed Watermark text to PDF documents* probably is buggy. Please post at least the pivotal parts.